# How to pass a list of objects from adapter to activity via broadcast receiver in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, broadcastreceiver

I have a situation where I need to pass a list from adapter to activity, then pass that same list from activity to another adapter. So, I am passing a list from adapter to activity like this, and it works.

```
if(filteredList.isNotEmpty()){
var json = Gson().toJson(filteredList)
intentPassList.putExtra("filteredList", json)
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(holder.context).sendBroadcast(intentPassList)
}
```

Next, I am receiving my list successfully like this in my activity class

```
  private val receiverFilteredList = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            var recList = intent.getStringExtra("filteredList")
            if (recList != null){
                var token: TypeToken<ArrayList<Model?>?> = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<Model?>?>() {}
                myFilteredList = Gson().fromJson(recList, token.type) // list is received correctly
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I need to pass this received list to another adapter (recycler view) and my idea was to do this in onCreate in my activity

```
private var myFilteredList: ArrayList<Model> = arrayListOf()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiverFilteredList, IntentFilter("filteredList"))

 if (myFilteredList?.isNotEmpty() == true){
            adapter = NewAdapter(myFilteredList!!)
            myRecycler?.layoutManager = manager
            myRecycler?.adapter = adapter
        } else {
            adapterInfo = NewAdapter(completeList)
            myRecycler?.layoutManager = manager
            myRecycler?.adapter = adapter
        }
}
}
```

but it always sends completeList to adapter, because myFilteredList is null. How can i correctly pass received list in receiver to myFilteredList in onCreate?

NewAdapterClass

```
class NewAdapter(var itemList: ArrayList<Model>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<NewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var getContext: Context

    class ViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var x: TextView = view.txtX
        val y: TextView = view.txtY
        val z: TextView = view.txtZ
        val localPreferances = PreferencesManager()
        val context: Context = view.context
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        getContext = parent.context
        val layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.listview_item_list_layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(layoutView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

            var receivedList = itemList[position]

            if (receivedList?.dataA != null) {
                holder.y?.text = "${receivedList?.dataA}"
            } else holder.y?.text = ""

            if (receivedList?.dataB != null) {
                holder.x?.text = "${receivedList?.dataB}"
            } else holder.x?.text = ""

            if (receivedList?.dataC != null) {
                holder.z?.text = "${receivedList?.dataC}"
            } else holder.z?.text = ""
    }

        override fun getItemCount() = itemList.size
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post your adapter class implementation as well?

Comment: I have added my adapter class. I need to pass this list from Activity's onCreate because if I dont, I get layout skipped error, and it shows nothing. So the idea was to receive list in Broadcast receiver inside activity class, than pass it to Oncreate in that same class, and from there via if statement control which list is passed to NewAdapter. But I cant fill myFIlteredList in onCreate, that is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inform `Adapter` about changes to it's data source which is `List` in your case, also `myFilteredList = Gson().fromJson(recList, token.type)` will create new instance of `ArrayList` and assign it to `myFilteredList`, but the initial instance provided to your adapter was different

```
private val receiverFilteredList = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        var recList = intent.getStringExtra("filteredList")
        if (recList != null){
            var token: TypeToken<ArrayList<Model?>?> = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<Model?>?>() {}
            myFilteredList.clear() //clear existing data 
            myFilteredList.addAll(Gson().fromJson(recList, token.type)) // add new data
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() //reset the list
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort but myFilteredList is still null.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change approach, broadcast receiver wasn't working for me. I sent the list (Gson().toJson) from adapter via Intent.putExtra, and in the activity I received it like this

```
recList= intent.getStringExtra("filteredList")

if (recList!= null){
   var token: TypeToken<ArrayList<Model?>?> = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<Model?>?>() {}
            myFilteredList?.clear()
            myFilteredList= Gson().fromJson(recList, token.type)
}
```

Now everything is working fine.